# I have made a JFrame which I want to put in an HTML script. (I was going to use a JApplet but it has been deprecated)

Tags: java, html, swing, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, I have coded a frame which I want to put into an HTML file so I can run it in my browser, how do I do this now that I cannot use JApplet? I have found this documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html and this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html but I am new to programming and find this difficult to follow. I don't know for instance how I would go about putting my class files and the image that I used in a separate directory nor do I know how I go about signing my application so that it will run in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to put into an HTML file so I can run it in my browser,

You can use the `Desktop` class. This class allows you to access default applications from your desktop.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial o [How to Integrate With the Desktop class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 1):

See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Note that is one of my 'copy/paste comments' that does not explicitly mention `JFrame` based apps., however the links are still relevant in that Oracle & browser makers would not be phasing out support for applets if they **wanted** programmers to keep trying to shove rich client apps (e.g. Swing GUIs) into thin client web pages.

OTOH you can offer a `JFrame` (or a `JApplet`) to be launched from a link in a web page to end up free floating on the desktop of the user by using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Even then, it is not a simple matter for the programmer or the end user. The programmer needs to ensure the app is digitally signed using a code signing certificate issued by a CA (usually they are expensive). The end user used to just be able to click the link, 'OK' the prompts produced by the Java virtual machine, and see the app appear on-screen. But now most browsers will download the launch file to the local file system rather than directly hand it to the JVM to be launched. So the user faces an extra step in explicitly finding the downloaded launch file and double clicking it.

This is all due to security concerns related to bugs in the plug-ins that run things in web pages. So if you were to find a way around all these hoops, please let us know. **It is a security bug that requires urgent fixing.**